# Выкатывающийся хедер при скролле вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, ecmascript-6

У меня есть страничка, в ней хедер (шапка сайта).
Как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы шапка была не видна, а при скролле вверх, она появлялась? Т.е. создавался эффект "выкатывания" шапки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример jQuery:

```js
var $header = $(".header")
var scroll = 0
var active = "active"
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scroll) {
    $header.addClass(active)
  } else {
    $header.removeClass(active)
  }
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

section {height: 100vh;}
.one {background-color: chocolate;}
.two {background-color: mistyrose;}
.three {background-color: gold;}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<section class="one"></section>
<section class="two"></section>
<section class="three"></section>
```

update для автора

```js
var $header = $(".header")
var scroll = 0
var active = "active"
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scroll) {
    $header.addClass(active)
  } else {
    $header.removeClass(active)
  }
})
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

section {height: 100vh;}
.one {background-color: chocolate;}
.two {background-color: mistyrose;}
.three {background-color: gold;}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.active {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">Header</div>
<section class="one"></section>
<section class="two"></section>
<section class="three"></section>
```

Comment: Не, не совсем то. Нужно, чтобы пользователь мог сразу наверх скроллить, и тем самым видел шапку

Comment: Ваше решение меня натолкнуло но одну мысль. Если пользователь скроллит вниз, затем наверх, и при позиции скролла = 0, то можно header - у добавлять или удалять класс, тем самым получится +- нужный эффект.

Comment: в общем, есть страничка. Есть шапка сайта и контент. При загрузке страницы шапка не видна и пользователю показывается сразу контент. Но, если он скроллит колесиком или по скроллу справа вверх, то как бы появляется шапка

Comment: Не совсем понял предпоследнее предложение, т.е. чтобы шапка появлялась при  первом скролле?

Comment: А если не сделать блок fixed? Такая реализация подойдет? Просто ведь могут быть резкие толчки

Comment: Все равно не совсем то :D Мне нужно чтобы шапка не была фиксированной. Т.е. расположение такое: шапка - контент, просто шапку он изначально не видит

Comment: Да. Она изначально идет выше первой секции. "Скрыл" я ее просто поставив margin-top: -80px. Но при такой реализации, если я правильно понимаю, пользователь никак не сможет сразу скроллить вверх?

Comment: Да, получается так. Что он не может изначально скроллить вверх. К, сожалению, этого не избежать, верно?

Comment: Понял! Спасибо большое за помощь, и за реализацию :)

Answer (score 1):

Запомнить текущую позицию скролла и повесить на страницу событие прокрутки. При прокрутке сравнить значение предыдущей позиции скрола с текущей позицией, чтобы определить в какую сторону идёт прокрутка и если она идёт вверх, то показать header

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, попробую